# Jackson Electrodynamics: spherical coordinates and azimuth symmetry - potential due to a charge

Tags: electrostatics, potential, coordinate-systems, voltage, gauss-law

In Jackson Electrodynamics, chapter 3.

We saw that for an azimuth symmetry, we have,

$$
\Phi(r, \theta) = \sum_{l=0}^{+\infty} \left(A_l r^l + B_l r^{-(l+1)} \right) P_l \cos(\theta)
$$

[image: jackson]

Then in the books, it says that the potential in $\vec{x}$ due to a charge in $\vec{x}'$  is given by

$$
\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|} = \sum_{l=0}^{+\infty} \frac{r^l_<}{r^{l+1}_>} P_l(\cos\gamma)
$$

Where $r_<$ is min(r,r') and $r_>$ is max(r,r').

So $\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|} = \Phi$ ? And how do we get this above result ?

If I'm right because we are outside the sphere, $A_l \rightarrow 0$ so that the potential diminish as $r \rightarrow \infty$ but then I still do not get the above result.

Then it says that we can turn the axes in a way that $\vec{x}'$ is on the axe $z$ and as a consequence, $\gamma$ become the azimuth angle "$\theta$".

But then again I don't understand the next, it says that the potential admits the following developpment,

$$\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|} = \sum_{l=0}^{+\infty} \left(A_l r^l + B_l r^{-(l+1)} \right) P_l \cos(\gamma)$$

Again so the potential $\Phi$ is $\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|}$? Why?

Comment: It’s the distance from the charge, like $1/r$ but for when the charge isn’t at the origin.

Comment: I know but so why $\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|} = \sum_{l=0}^{+\infty} \left(A_l r^l + B_l r^{-(l+1)} \right) P_l \cos(\gamma) = \Phi(r, \theta)$ ?

Comment: *I know*. But you wrote “the potential $\Phi$ is $\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|}$? Why?”.

Comment: Regarding the expansion, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Definition_via_generating_function) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Expanding_a_1/r_potential). It is essentially a Taylor series and Legendre’s *definition* of the Legendre polynomials.

Comment: if you have troubles with any of this I would recommend you to read a book about mathematical methods in physics first or else you will just get massively confused and probably won't get much out of it as u go on. The book isn't easy to begin with but being confident in the maths and having a reference to look stuff like this up will make it much easier to follow. like what the motivation behind some methods used are. for example why using a fourier transform in some places is a natural thing to do or why the expansion of your 1/r gives you a sum of legendre polynomials etc..

Comment: Yeah I've figured out that it is the generating function of the Legendre Polynomials. By the way I had a course about math methods one year ago but I totally forgot about that specific generating function + didn't expect to encounter that here. Thanks anyway !